# how to reconnect / rediscover automatically with flutter flutter_blue_plus?

Tags: flutter

I want my device (a bike) to automatically reconnect / rediscover after it has been disconnected because of bluetooth range or bluetooth being turned off on the phone. This is the code it uses to search and connect to the bike.

```
searchForBikes() async {
  FlutterBluePlus flutterBlue = FlutterBluePlus.instance;
  await flutterBlue.isAvailable;
  flutterBlue.setLogLevel(LogLevel.critical);
  flutterBlue.startScan(
    // timeout: const Duration(seconds: 4)
  );

  for (var device in await flutterBlue.connectedDevices) {
    for (Bike bike in bikes) {
      if (bike.bluetoothName.contains(device.name)) {
        RealBikeConnection(bike)
            .connect(device, autoConnect: true)
            .then((_) => setState(() {}));
        break;
      }
    }
  }

  Set<String> tryingToConnectWith = {};
  flutterBlue.scanResults.listen((results) {
    for (ScanResult r in results) {
      if (tryingToConnectWith.contains(r.device.name)) {
        continue;
      }

      for (Bike bike in bikes) {
        if (bike.bluetoothName.contains(r.device.name)) {
          tryingToConnectWith.add(r.device.name);
          RealBikeConnection(bike)
              .connect(r.device, autoConnect: true)
              .then((_) => setState(() {}));
          break;
        }
      }
    }
  });
}
```

I've tried multiple ways to check if the device state is either disconnected or null and then reconnecting / rediscovering after that. To do that I've used the following code. It didn't work and still only reconnected after reopening the app.

```
Future<void> connection() async {
  StreamSubscription<BluetoothDeviceState> subscription;

  List<BluetoothDevice> devices = await FlutterBluePlus.instance.connectedDevices;
  if (devices.isNotEmpty) {
    BluetoothDevice device = devices.first;
    subscription = device.state.listen((state) {
      if (state == BluetoothDeviceState.disconnected) {
        print("Device disconnected, restarting scan...");
        searchForBikes().then((_) {
          print("Scan started");
        });
      }
    });
  } else if (devices.isEmpty){
    searchForBikes();
  }
}
```